# Link To Foreignkey in Admin Causes AttributeError When Debug Is False

Tags: python, django, django-admin, foreign-keys

I have used the following code in my models.py file:

Create hyperlink to foreignkey

```
class ModelAdminWithForeignKeyLinksMetaclass(MediaDefiningClass): 

    def __getattr__(cls, name):

        def foreign_key_link(instance, field):
            target = getattr(instance, field)
            return u'<a href="../../%s/%s/%s">%s</a>' % (
                target._meta.app_label, target._meta.module_name, target.id, unicode(target))

        if name[:8] == 'link_to_':
            method = partial(foreign_key_link, field=name[8:])
            method.__name__ = name[8:]
            method.allow_tags = True
            setattr(cls, name, method)
            return getattr(cls, name)
        raise AttributeError
```

In admin.py list_display I've added link_to to the beginning of each field I want a foreignkey link on. This works really well however when I turn debug off I get an attribute error. Any suggestions?

Comment: "When I turn debug off": Are you literally talking about simply changing DEBUG=True to DEBUG=False generates the error, or is it working in your dev environment but failing on your production server?

Comment: Even on my dev server when I set debug=False it generates this error.

Comment: Interesting. The value of DEBUG literally has nothing to do with anything you have going on there. Can you post a traceback?

Comment: This might seem like a strange question but how do I get my traceback with debug set to false?

Comment: OK so I've been emailed the traceback. It is at http://pastebin.com/S4qPm5md.

Comment: Can you try to find strange stuff happening in the admin with TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID?

Comment: Well it seems like you got the traceback anyways, but in the future you should check out django-sentry. It's an excellent debugging tool for your production environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. For the time being I've just hard coded the links for each field I need to link back as there were very few fields that needed this. I know this isn't a fix and will check it with what has been suggested at a later stage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I stumbled on exactly the same problem, luckily, I've fixed it.

The original solution (the one you used) comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470285/foreign-keys-in-django-admin-list-display), my solution is based on it:

```
class ForeignKeyLinksMetaclass(MediaDefiningClass):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        new_class = super(
            ForeignKeyLinksMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        def foreign_key_link(instance, field):
            target = getattr(instance, field)
            return u'<a href="../../%s/%s/%d/">%s</a>' % (
                target._meta.app_label, target._meta.module_name,
                target.id, unicode(target)
            )

        for name in new_class.list_display:
            if name[:8] == 'link_to_':
                method = partial(foreign_key_link, field=name[8:])
                method.__name__ = name[8:]
                method.allow_tags = True
                setattr(new_class, name, method)

        return new_class
```

Well, the only thing you need is to replace the original *ModelAdminWithForeignKeyLinksMetaclass* with the one above.

However, it's not the end. The most interesting part is why the original solution causes problems. The answer to this question lies [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.3.x/django/contrib/admin/validation.py#L31) (line 31) and [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.3.x/django/contrib/admin/util.py#L244) (line 244).

When DEBUG is on Django tries to validate all registered ModelAdmins (first link). There *cls* is a **class** SomeAdmin (i.e. an instance of its metaclass). When *hasattr* is called, python tries to find an attribute *field* in class *SomeAdmin* or in one of its super classes. Since it is impossible, __getattr__ of  its class (i.e. *SomeAdmin*'s metaclass) is called, where a new method is added to class *SomeAdmin*. Hence, when it comes to rendering the interface, *SomeAdmin* is already patched and Django is able to find the required field (second link).

When DEBUG is False, Django skips the validation. When the interface is rendered Django tries to find a field (again, second link), but this time SomeAdmin is not patched, moreover *model_admin* is not class *SomeAdmin*, it is its **instance**. Thus, trying to find an attribute *name* in *model_admin*, python is unable to do this, neither it is able to find it in its class (*SomeAdmin*) as well as in any of its super classes, so an exception is raised.

Comment: if like me, you add functions to your list_display, you should do this change: if type(name) == type('') and name[:8] == 'link_to_':

Comment: @fceruti yeah, you're right, but I think a better way to do this is: if isinstance(name, basestring) and name[:8] == 'link_to_':

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem with a similar list_display hack ( http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2887/ ), and this would've taken me ages to figure out.

Comment: This answer could probably be improved by using a reverse URL instead of a hard-coded relative path.

Comment: To me this solution produces an error ("metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases") for some reason. However, there seems to be a similar version that works for me, in 'django-model-admin-helper' (see code in https://github.com/Arpaso/django-model-admin-helper/blob/master/src/admin_helpers.py)

Answer (score 1):

I uses stepank's implementation, but had to alter it slightly to fit my use-case.

I basically just added support for 'ModelAdmin.readonly_fields' and 'ModelAdmin.fields' to support the 'link_to_'-syntax.

A slight change to the link creation also allowed me to support a link to a different APP.Model, in my case the built-in django.contrib.auth.models.user.

Thanks for the nice work @stepank and @Itai Tavor.

I hope this is useful for somebody else.

---

DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME is defined in my settings.py and I use it for most of my logging. If you don't have it defined, you will get errors when using the following code. You can either define your own DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME in settings.py (it is just a simple string) or you just remove all references to the logger in the code below.

```
'''
Created on Feb 23, 2012

@author: daniel

Purpose: Provides a 'link_to_<foreignKeyModel>' function for ModelAdmin 
         implementations. This is based on the following work:

original: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3157065/193165
fixed original: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7192721/193165
'''
from functools      import partial
from django.forms   import MediaDefiningClass

import logging
from public.settings import DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME
logger = logging.getLogger(DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME)

class ForeignKeyLinksMetaclass(MediaDefiningClass):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        new_class = super(
            ForeignKeyLinksMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        def foreign_key_link(instance, field):
            target = getattr(instance, field)
            ret_url = u'<a href="../../%s/%s/%d/">%s</a>' % (
                      target._meta.app_label, target._meta.module_name,
                      target.id, unicode(target)
                      ) 
            #I don't know how to dynamically determine in what APP we currently
            #are, so this is a bit of a hack to enable links to the 
            #django.contrib.auth.models.user
            if "auth" in target._meta.app_label and "user" in target._meta.module_name:
                ret_url = u'<a href="/admin/%s/%s/%d/">%s</a>' % (
                          target._meta.app_label, target._meta.module_name,
                          target.id, unicode(target)
                          )                    
            return ret_url

        def _add_method(name):
            if name is None: return
            if isinstance(name, basestring) and name[:8] == 'link_to_':
                try:
                    method = partial(foreign_key_link, field=name[8:])
                    method.__name__ = name[8:]
                    method.allow_tags = True
                    #in my app the "user" field always points to django.contrib.auth.models.user
                    #and I want my users to see that when they edit "client" data
                    #"Client" is another model, that has a 1:1 relationship with 
                    #django.contrib.auth.models.user
                    if "user" in name[8:]: 
                        method.short_description = "Auth User"
                    setattr(new_class, name, method)
                except Exception, ex:
                    logger.debug("_add_method(%s) failed: %s" % (name, ex))
        #make this work for InlineModelAdmin classes as well, who do not have a
        #.list_display attribute
        if hasattr(new_class, "list_display") and not new_class.list_display is None:
            for name in new_class.list_display:
                _add_method(name)
        #enable the 'link_to_<foreignKeyModel>' syntax for the ModelAdmin.readonly_fields
        if not new_class.readonly_fields is None:
            for name in new_class.readonly_fields:
                _add_method(name)
        #enable the 'link_to_<foreignKeyModel>' syntax for the ModelAdmin.fields
        if not new_class.fields is None:
            for name in new_class.fields:
                _add_method(name)

        return new_class
```

Comment: I don't test in your implementation, just in the @stepank but probably you should add:

    if not target: return None

Because without it will break when you have ForeignKey thats points to Null, like when you use blank=True and Null=True.